# mysql: SELECT all items in common between two users

Tags: mysql

i have two tables

item_tb

```
| item_id | user_id |
---------------------
```

user_tb

```
| user_id | user_name |
-----------------------
```

in item_tb i have lots of items that belongs to various user in user_tb, an item can belong to one or more users...

**so, given the userid A and userid B how can I do a mysql query to select all the items the belong both to userA and userB?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    select i.item_id
      from item_tb i
inner join user_tb u ON i.user_id = u.user_id
     where i.user_id IN (42, 43)
  group by i.item_id
    having count(*) = 2
```

Where 42 and 43 are those users.

Comment: thanks! i actually realized that my question was not complete. because it involves a third table...shoudl I start a new question or update this one?

Comment: @camelCase: since you already have checked this answer - seems like it helped ;-)