# Query common Groups between two Users

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'd like to query common Groups between two Users.

This are my models:

## User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
end
```

## Group Model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
end
```

## Join Table Model between User and Group

```
class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Lets say, I have two Users A and B, I'd like to get the Groups that the user A and the user B are members of in common.

### For example:

User A is member of Groups **[W, X, Y]**

User B is member of Groups **[W, X, Z]**

Using this query the expected answer would be the Groups **[W, X]**

(Groups_From_A ∩ Groups_From_B)

I have found some answers for this, but they are not using only the active records:

```
user_a.groups & user_b.groups
```

I do not want to do this in memory, but in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it!! \o/

With a little help of Mr. @zerkms answer posted **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177131/mysql-select-all-items-in-common-between-two-users)**.

Well, I knew this was tricky but turned out to be easier than I thought.

#### The final query:

```
Group.joins(:users).where(users: { id: [user_a.id, user_b.id] }).group("groups.id").having("COUNT(users.id)=2")
```

#### Explanation:

I queried for the Groups from users A and B:

```
Group.joins(:users).where(users: { id: [user_a.id, user_b.id] }).(...)
```

It gave me an array with all groups from the two users, even repeated.

So I group them and get where the count where 2. Because when we have a group repeated, it means that this group were queried from User A and User B.

```
   (...).group("groups.id").having("COUNT(users.id)=2")
```

It worked fine, but if you have a better or a different solution, I'd be glad to see.

Thanks guys and thanks Mr. @zerkms, I just "translated" your answer to RoR.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question, and maybe someone with more SQL skills can provide a more optimized answer, but here's what I came up with that will do what you want in the database:

First, you have to provide the ids of User A and User B:

```
relation = User.where id: [user_a.id, user_b.id]
```

To that we can chain our joins to the groups association:

```
relation = relation.joins(:groups)
```

That will return the groups of those two users, however, we want to minimize duplicates:

```
results = relation.select("DISTINCT(groups.id), users.*, groups.*")
```

That `DISTINCT` SQL statement will reduce our duplicates but not all the way, since when we get the results back in Ruby, ActiveRecord will assign the groups of each user to each user object even though some are the same between both users.

So, we `map` and `uniq` them:

```
results.flat_map(&:groups).uniq
```

This gives us the union of both users' groups.

The full query:

```
User.where(id: [user_a.id, user_b.id]).
     joins(:groups).
     select("DISTINCT(groups.id), users.*, groups.*").
     flat_map(&:groups).
     uniq
```

Here's the SQL statement this will execute:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(groups.id), users.*, groups.* 
FROM "users" 
INNER JOIN "groups_memberships" 
  ON "groups_memberships"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
INNER JOIN "groups" 
  ON "groups"."id" = "groups_memberships"."group_id" 
WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2)
```

Notice that the key to this approach is knowing the User IDs ahead of time, then simply joining the `groups` table. After we get those results back we just ask for each user's locations and we `uniq` them.

**UPDATE**

Here's a reverse way to deal with this: Query from the Group to the User:

```
Group.joins(groups_memberships: :user).
      where(users: { id: [user_a.id, user_b.id] }).
      uniq
```

This will execute this SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "groups".* 
FROM "groups" 
INNER JOIN "groups_memberships" 
ON "groups_memberships"."location_id" = "groups"."id" 
INNER JOIN "users" 
ON "users"."id" = "groups_memberships"."user_id" 
WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2)
```

This approach is more optimal in the sense that it does everything in the database and no `uniq`ing in memory. Notice how the `uniq` method in this case added the `DISTINCT` to the query itself and will return the same results.

**CORRECTION**

The previous solution was returning a union and not an intersection. For lack of a more pure SQL answer I'll leave this:

```
results = Group.joins(groups_memberships: :user).
                where(users: { id: [user_a.id, user_b.id] }).
                uniq

intersection = results.select do |group| 
  [user_a.id, user_b.id].all? { |id| group.user_ids.include? id }
end
```

Downside is it will do an additional query per group but will at least get you the intersection from the union until you find a pure SQL solution. If you find one I'd love to see it!

Comment: Distinct is not a function

Comment: Corrected my wording. Thanks.

Comment: But you're still pretending that it's a function. The parentheses are meaningless (and a little misleading). The last bit's good though.

Comment: Thanks, though I'll leave the parens since the query still works correctly and this question isn't directly about SQL syntax.

Comment: Hi @diego.greyrobot, thanks for the answer! I've tested it but that is not what I want. In that way I get the UNION between the groups from User A and User B, actually I want the INTERSECTION between them. In my example on question the correct response from the query is [W, X], if I use your answer it would be [W, X, Y, Z].

Comment: This is trickier than I thought! I'm not sure how to go about this in pure SQL but I'll at least provide a simple tack on solution in Ruby. Sorry about that though!